# Software Based CMS that allows you to put the admin console on a different port?

Tags: cms

I'd prefer Joomla, Wordpress, or Drupal.  But so far I haven't been able to find one of these.

If you can put the admin interface on another port, it is really great for your security.

Comment: The port has very little to do with security, if anything. This is easily achievable with `nginx` since it can proxy http requests to multiple `php-fpm` instances. You'll gain virtually nothing security-wise, since the port can easily be obtained.

Comment: @Mjh okay so I meant port and ip; because I want to bind it to the localhost address so that it can only be accessed via ssh and a public key with a pass phrase.  That combined with some browser profile settings will allow me to access the admin console only over ssh.

Comment: If you want to secure this access, you can always use client-side certificates. It removes the need to fiddle with port, ip, this and that. If a client (browser) supplies a certificate that the server can verify, you can access the admin page, otherwise you get 401 forbidden. [Here's some reading about it](http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi).

Comment: @Mjh you mean self signed certificates?

Comment: You can use self-signed certificates or CA certs (I use CA ones to sign certificates that I hand out for special authentication purposes described in the text I linked).

Comment: @Mjh I think using both techniques would get it even more secured.   Might slow it down a bit though...

Comment: Fiddling with port and IP does nothing for security. Strong authentication, encryption, eliminating man in the middle etc. - that increases security of your app. You can still fiddle with port / IP, but adding more water to water does not make water "wetter". It's up to you what you want to do :) good luck!

Comment: @Mjh SSH only has the chance for MiM attacks the first time it connects as far as I know;  so if you can't access the port unless you're connected locally (via ssh) then how is there a MiM attack?

Comment: There are ways to avoid MITM, for example - by using strong two factor authentication such as FIDO U2F. That's why I mentioned strong authentication. However, the gist of my comment(s) is that you're after strong authentication mechanisms rather than software which serves admin pages based on ip/port. This configuration you're after is done on web-server's side, not on the php app side. Server acts as the primary "firewall" and decides whether to let requests through or not. Personally, I'd go with nginx and client-side certificates to protect sensitive URIs.

Comment: If you want to have specific URLs accessible only from localhost ("I want to bind it to the localhost address"), that can easily be achieved via the web server configuration (e.g. `deny_from` and `allow_from` directives with Apache), no matter what CMS you're using. As this part is the only requirement your question mentions, I'd say it's much too broad – as this way it matches each and every CMS existing. Hence I'm putting it on hold now.

Comment: In Joomla, the [Akeeba admin tools](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/admin-tools.html) has functionality that makes it very easy to lock down the admin panel in a variety of ways. Since you already like Joomla, buy yourself a license for Akeeba (it's not expensive) and you'll get as secure an admin panel as you could possibly want. (trust me, I know of goverment agencies running this stuff that have put it through a full security audit). One thing it doesn't do is anything with the port number, but as others have said already that really wouldn't do much for your security anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that any cms platform itself will allow you to specify an HTTP port; that's part of the web server (apache, nginx) configuration itself.

So, the good news is that you can set up redirect rules and so forth to only allow administration requests to travel over whatever port you want. For instance, in Drupal, all administration requests will go through `/admin/...`, so configure your rules to only accept such requests over a certain port.

However, I don't know if other platforms have similar identifiers for admin requests.